# How to construct a matrix for a heatmap or a contour plot, but with NA events?

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

How can I construct a heatmap like matrix from 3 variables, 2 categorical and 1 numeric, in which certain events do not occur. My dplyr code overlooks those events and misses about 20 cavities in the surface plot that I'd like to make. For that I need an accurate matrix. But this is rather complicated.

What I consider a NA event is a maximum time for which two categorical events (Modeling and Discourse) do not occur simultaneously. So a point of null time observations (NA), not even zero.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(`Modeling Code` = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"MA", "OFF", "P", "SM", "V"), class = "factor"), `Discourse Code` = structure(c(8L, 
5L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 
8L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 
9L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
6L), .Label = c("AG", "C", "D", "DA", "G", "J", "OFF", "Q", "S"
), class = "factor"), Time_Processed = c(1.3833, 1.4333, 1.4667, 
1.5333, 1.6167, 1.65, 1.6833, 1.7333, 1.8, 1.8667, 1.9833, 2.05, 
2.1333, 2.1667, 2.2167, 2.3, 2.3167, 2.3667, 2.5667, 2.5833, 
2.6, 2.7833, 2.8, 2.8167, 2.8667, 3.0167, 3.0333, 3.05, 3.05, 
3.1, 3.1833, 3.2667, 3.3, 3.3333, 3.4167, 3.45, 3.4833, 3.5667, 
3.6, 3.7, 3.7167, 3.8, 3.95, 4, 4.05, 4.15, 4.1667, 4.15, 4.2167, 
4.3, 4.3833, 4.4, 4.4833, 4.5833, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.8333, 4.8833, 
5, 5.05, 5.1, 5.2167, 5.4333, 5.45, 5.6, 5.7, 5.9167, 6.25, 6.2667, 
6.2833, 6.4667, 6.5167, 6.5333, 6.55, 6.6667, 6.7167, 6.9, 6.95, 
7.05, 7.05, 7.45, 7.6167, 7.7667, 7.7833, 7.8333, 8, 8.0167, 
8.05, 8.1, 8.2833, 8.3167, 8.4333, 8.4667, 8.5, 8.55, 8.8833, 
9.2667, 9.3167, 9.3333, 9.35, 9.5167, 9.6833, 9.7167, 9.7667, 
9.7833, 9.8333, 9.9, 9.9667, 10.0667, 10.0833, 10.15, 10.2, 10.2667, 
10.2667, 10.3, 10.35, 10.3667, 10.4, 10.7, 10.7833, 10.9, 11.1333, 
11.1833, 11.2167, 11.2333, 11.25, 11.3, 11.35, 11.4167, 11.4667, 
11.5333, 11.5667, 11.6667, 11.85, 11.8667, 11.8833, 12.25, 12.3167, 
12.7167, 12.7333, 12.8, 12.85, 12.9333, 12.9667, 13.2667, 13.3167, 
13.4, 13.4167, 13.5, 13.55, 13.6333, 13.9, 13.95, 13.9667, 14.05, 
14.0833, 14.3167, 14.35, 14.3667, 14.4333, 14.4667, 14.5, 14.5333, 
14.5833, 14.5833, 14.6167, 14.6667, 14.7167, 14.75, 14.7667, 
15.05, 15.0833, 15.25, 15.4333, 15.4833, 15.5167, 15.6, 15.6333, 
15.7167, 15.7333, 15.7667, 15.8667, 16.0167, 16.2, 16.2833, 16.3333, 
16.3833, 16.45, 16.6, 16.6667, 16.9333, 16.9667, 17, 17.0333, 
17.0833, 17.1167, 17.2167, 17.35, 17.4333, 17.55, 17.6, 17.6167, 
17.65, 17.7, 17.7167, 17.75, 17.7833, 17.8833, 17.9333, 17.9833, 
18.0167, 18.0333, 18.05, 18.0667, 18.1, 18.1667, 18.2, 18.3667, 
18.45, 18.5333, 18.6333, 18.6667, 18.7333, 18.85, 18.8833, 18.9833, 
19.0333, 19.0667, 19.3833, 19.5333, 19.6333, 19.6667, 19.7167, 
19.9333, 19.9667, 20.05, 20.2333, 20.3667, 20.4333, 20.5, 20.5167, 
20.5167, 20.55, 20.6167, 20.7167, 20.7667, 20.8167, 20.8667, 
21.1333, 21.1833, 21.2, 21.2167, 21.2333, 21.2833, 21.3, 21.5, 
21.5833, 21.6333, 21.6667, 21.6833, 21.6833, 21.8167, 21.8833, 
22.1333, 22.1667, 22.35, 22.4333, 22.5, 22.5333, 22.5833, 22.6, 
22.6, 22.65, 22.6667, 22.7167, 22.75, 22.8833, 23.0667, 23.0833, 
23.1167, 23.3167, 23.35, 23.3667, 23.45, 23.5, 23.7667, 23.9833, 
24.1833, 24.2167, 24.25, 24.2833, 24.5167, 24.5333, 24.6833, 
24.7833, 24.7833, 24.8, 24.8, 24.8667, 25.3833, 25.4333, 25.4833, 
25.5, 25.5167, 25.55, 25.5667, 25.5833, 25.6667, 25.7, 26, 26.1333, 
26.1667, 26.2, 26.2333, 26.2667, 26.4, 26.4333, 26.4667, 26.5, 
26.5167, 26.6667, 26.7, 26.8, 27.0833, 27.1833, 27.2, 27.2, 27.45, 
27.5667, 27.6667, 27.7, 27.75, 27.7667, 27.7667, 27.8, 27.8333, 
28.0333, 28.35, 28.6333, 28.6333, 28.7833, 28.8, 28.85, 29, 29.1833, 
29.3333, 29.6667, 29.7333, 29.8, 29.8833, 29.9, 29.9333, 30.0667, 
30.1, 30.1833, 30.2167, 30.25, 30.3, 30.3833, 30.5, 30.55, 30.7167, 
31.0167, 31.45, 31.6, 31.8, 31.8333, 32.0167, 32.15, 32.15, 32.1667, 
32.2167, 32.2167, 32.2333, 32.3833, 32.6167, 32.6667, 32.7, 32.7167, 
32.7333, 32.75, 32.9, 33.0833, 33.1333, 33.1833)), row.names = c(NA, 
-386L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Modeling Code", 
"Discourse Code", "Time_Processed"))
```

Looks a little bit like this:

```
df[1:10,]
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   `Modeling Code` `Discourse Code` Time_Processed
   <fct>           <fct>                     <dbl>
 1 P               Q                          1.38
 2 P               G                          1.43
 3 P               Q                          1.47
 4 P               AG                         1.53
 5 P               S                          1.62
 6 P               C                          1.65
 7 P               Q                          1.68
 8 V               J                          1.73
 9 P               G                          1.80
10 SM              J                          1.87
```

If I construct a matrix for my heatmap For the two categorical variables `Modeling Code` and `Discourse Code`, it looks a little bit like this:

```
with(df, table(`Discourse Code`, `Modeling Code`)) %>% prop.table() %>% as.data.frame() -> z

ggplot(data = z, aes(x = `Modeling.Code`, y = `Discourse.Code`, fill = Freq)) + theme_bw() + geom_tile() + geom_text(size = 3, aes(label = Freq))
```

[image: Relevent Heatmap]

This is a heatmap of the freqency of occurence of each matching categorical varibale so (C & MA) occur simutaneously about 10.6% of the time, while many pairs of categorical factors do not sumulatenously occur at all. These are the ones with 0 quantity. All those factors add up to 1, accounting for 100% of all pairs of Modeling and Discourse Codes.

**If you count the number of zeroes (no occurring pairs)** in this data-set you will see that there are twenty zeroes and this is important.

I was interested in the times at which these pairs occur so I decided to make a contour plot with plot_ly from my original dataset.

```
 plot_ly(data = df, x = ~ `Modeling Code`, y = ~ `Discourse Code`, z = ~ `Time_Processed`, type = "contour")
```

[image: Contour Plot]

Inspection of this contour plot with an interactive mouse shows that the Time points of "Time_Processed" are the maximum values of the "Modeling Codes" and "Discourse Codes"

So I generate those points with dplyr:

```
df %>%
+     group_by(`Modeling Code`, `Discourse Code`) %>%
+     summarise(max_time = max(Time_Processed))
# A tibble: 34 x 3
# Groups:   Modeling Code [?]
   `Modeling Code` `Discourse Code` max_time
   <fct>           <fct>               <dbl>
 1 A               AG                   9.97
 2 A               C                   32.7 
 3 A               D                    4.17
 4 A               J                   33.2 
 5 A               Q                   32.8 
 6 A               S                   32.7 
 7 MA              AG                  24.7 
 8 MA              C                   31.4 
 9 MA              D                   22.4 
10 MA              DA                  27.2 
# ... with 24 more rows
```

Hold up!!! There are only 34 entries, of maximum times, but the size of my heatmap is (6 x 9) = 54 cells. The 20 missing entries are the categorical pairs that yield zero. So I'm finding it very difficult to construct my matrix.

```
        A           MA         OFF            P        SM         V 
S     32.733      31.800       NA         30.3000    30.250     32.700
Q     32.750     27.1833       NA         30.5000    29.800     28.85
OFF   NA            NA         33.133       NA        NA        NA 
J    33.1833      26.5167      NA         30.7167   30.2167    31.8333
G    NA             NA         NA        11.8500      NA        NA 
DA   NA           20.72        NA            NA      29.8833    25.700
D   4.1667       22.235        NA          6.2667      NA       32.2167
C   32.6667       31.4500      NA         30.3833    29.9000    32.1500
AG  9.967         24.6833      NA         13.2667    30.0667    32.7167
```

This is the matrix (assuming I didn't make any manual mistakes) that I'd like to create based on my observations. The NAs are values that for the Modeling and Discourse Code pairs that do not occur, so it's the 20 entries that my dplyr summarise function with maximum time could not capture, but my heatmap did. So if I do that then I can tediously fill out this matrix.

My question is how can I construct this matrix? 
In addition, I would prefer that the matching values either show up as NAs or as -1, but not zero ... because my goal is to construct this matrix and then I can create a 3D surface plot that complements by contour plot so that I can accurately see the types of procedures that my subjects are implementing over an event that is about 30 minutes. So if those drop columns are interpreted as zero, then the surface plot will be wrong because at the beginning of the event (time 0) the subjects did not use those procedures.

Complex problems sometimes have simple solutions and it wasn't clear to me until I did a lot of experimentation with all existing functions. I figured out that dcast accomplished my goal. All the word noise was me trying to explain the complexity of my problem I was hoping you would understand.

```
dcast(data = FERMI_1, formula = `Discourse Code` ~ `Modeling Code`, value.var = "Time_Processed", fun.aggregate = max, fill = -1)
  Discourse Code       A      MA     OFF       P      SM       V
1             AG  9.9667 24.6833 -1.0000 13.2667 30.0667 32.7167
2              C 32.6667 31.4500 -1.0000 30.3833 29.9000 32.1500
3              D  4.1667 22.3500 -1.0000  6.2667 -1.0000 32.2167
4             DA -1.0000 27.2000 -1.0000 -1.0000 29.8833 25.7000
5              G -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 11.8500 -1.0000 -1.0000
6              J 33.1833 26.5167 -1.0000 30.7167 30.2167 31.8333
7            OFF -1.0000 -1.0000 33.1333 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000
8              Q 32.7500 27.1833 -1.0000 30.5000 29.8000 28.8500
9              S 32.7333 31.8000 -1.0000 30.3000 30.2500 32.7000
```

Comment: You cannot have "null events". `NULL` can only be used as a list element but not as an entry in an atomic vector. Use `NA`. Or use "". Just don't use NULL.

Comment: I apologize for my terminology error. Do you have any ideas about how to approach this problem?

Comment: If you have an object that supports the `is.na` and `[<-` functions then reassigning a numeric value of -1 to entries that currently are NA is as simple as `obj[ is.na(obj) ] <- -1`. (I cannot really tell if this is the request, since I got lost in the long presentation that didn't have a definite goal.) If on the other hand, the need is to first generate such a matrix from a long format data-obj named `df2` might be addressed by `obj <- xtabs(max_time ~`Modeling Code`+`Discourse Code`, data=df2)`

Comment: Yes, my goal was to construct a matrix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears my comment answered the question:

If you have an object that supports the is.na and [<- functions then reassigning a numeric value of -1 to entries that currently are NA is as simple as `obj[ is.na(obj) ] <- -1`. (I cannot really tell if this is the request, since I got lost in the long presentation that didn't have a definite goal.) If on the other hand, the need is to first generate such a matrix from a long format data-obj named df2 might be addressed by

```
 obj <- xtabs(max_time ~Modeling Code+Discourse Code, data=df2)
```

Comment: My goal was to construct the matrix that I showed which is the maximum time at which each of the Discourse Codes and Modeling Codes overlap, and I need that matrix to make a contour plot. I love the melt function, so I tried every function I could think of and used the opposite function dcast which actually constructs a wide dataframe and can give you a matrix with formulas and do substitutions: 

dcast(data = df2, formula = `Modeling Code` ~ `Discourse Code`, value.var = "Time_Processed", fun.aggregate = max, fill = -1)

I drew the matrix to show my goal which I just accomplished.